# Datatable con Ajax y Json en Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, json, datatable

Quiero listar datos en formato json en una datatable usando ajax pero no logro tabularlos, no logro detectar mi error. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

RUTAS

```
Route::get('/', 'DatatableController@inicio');
Route::get('/datos', 'DatatableController@datos');
```

CONTROLADOR

```
public function inicio(){
 return view('datatable');
}
public function datos(){
    $datos = [
        "ID" => 23,
        "Nombre" => "Omar",
        "Correo" => "omar@correo"
    ];          
    return $datos;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#users-table').DataTable({
            columns: [
                {name: "ID", data: "ID"},
                {name: "Nombre", data: "Nombre"},
                {name: "Correo", data: "Correo"}
            ],
            ajax:{                   
                url: '/datos',                  
            }
        });  
    });  
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes exactamente? ¿Hay algo en la consola del navegador? ¿Algún error en los logs de Laravel?

Comment: Sé más específico con tu problema, si requieres regresar los datos en json debes de hacerlo de la siguiente forma en tu controlador: `return response()->json($datos);`

Comment: @JaviMollá Me aparece el siguiente error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. Lo que quiero es que los datos que tengo en el controlador se impriman en la Datatable, pero no se imprimen, sólo me muestra la tabla con la fila de encabezados pero sin los datos.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Ya probé eso, amigo, pero me aparece el mismo error. No sé si mi error esté en la parte de ajax, o en el controlador.

Comment: Sólo me faltaba colocar los corchetes [ ] para agrupar los datos en el controlador. Solucionado. Gracias.